# How to create this type of numeric list?

Tags: r

I came across the following numeric list:

A:

```
1    2    3
3.4  4.5  5.7
```

where if I type in A[1] I get:

```
1
3.4
```

What type of list is this since class(A) only tells me its a 'numeric' class?

Also how do I create such a numeric list using two different lists?  Say:

```
List_1= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
List_2= c(4.3, 5.2, 6.4, 1.3, 4.9)
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the result `dput(A)` at the end of your question? Perhaps it is a named vector, e.g `c(a = 1, b = 2)`

Comment: `names(List_2) <- List_1` should do it

Comment: BTW, `A[1]` will work as you say only as long as the first element in the array also has the name `"1"`. That is, `A[1]` will always grab the first element regardless of the names, because the names are always `character`. The `1 2 3` over the values are actually strings, so to do what you say you would need to do `A["1"]`. BTW: this is not technically a `list` in R, it is a `vector`. In R, vectors: must be the same class (`numeric`) and cannot be "complex" (nested).

Comment: @markus that command outputs something like '1'=3.4, '2'=4.5, etc.

Comment: Markus you, Andrew Gustar and r2evans are right about it being a named vector.  Thank you Andrew Gustar for suggesting how to create the named vector.  Thank you for the information r2evans however I wanted to let you know that for some reason typing A[1] still gives me the first result despite the name not being '1'.